# Can't see SQL Server Spatial layers in GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, sql-server-spatial

I have a SQL Server Spatial database with a database called EDX. That database has a table called GEOMETRY_COLUMNS in its DBO schema. That table is populated with the spatial tables in the schema/database.

GeoServer has been configured with the right java driver.

I can create a Data Store in GeoServer for the EDX database, but when I go to add a Layer I get no entries from which to select to publish even though the GEOMETRY_COLUMNS table has entries.

Can anyone give me some pointers as to how to find out what is going wrong?

Comment: You need to turn up the logging level to developer in the global settings page, and then make the request again. Then [edit] your question with the **relevant** part of the log file.

Comment: I set logging to DEVELOPER, restarted GeoServer. The only log entry that refers to the EDX SQL Server database is:

2022-09-30 09:13:15,908 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded data store 'EDX', enabled

With no following entries like this 

2022-09-30 09:13:15,995 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded feature type .....

I have a table called dbo.geometry_columns in the EDX database. It is populated with data:

SELECT count(*)
  FROM [DEVDB].[dbo].[geometry_columns];

(No column name)
36

Comment: The structure of the geometry_columns table is

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[geometry_columns](
 [f_table_catalog] [varchar](128) NOT NULL,
 [f_table_schema] [varchar](128) NOT NULL,
 [f_table_name] [varchar](256) NOT NULL,
 [f_geometry_column] [varchar](256) NOT NULL,
 [coord_dimension] [int] NOT NULL,
 [srid] [int] NOT NULL,
 [type] [varchar](30) NOT NULL,
 [qgis_xmin] [float] NULL,
 [qgis_ymin] [float] NULL,
 [qgis_xmax] [float] NULL,
 [qgis_ymax] [float] NULL,
 [qgis_pkey] [varchar](128) NULL
)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was not to do with the geometry_columns table in a database/schema rather it was a user grant/permissions problem.

Sorry for any inconvenience caused.